# Using DropdownListFor ignoring the "selected" value I've set in the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

Here is the controller code:

```
EfCategoriaRepository efCategoriaRepository = new EfCategoriaRepository();
model.Categoria= new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var categoria in efCategoriaRepository.FindAllCategorias())
{
    model.Categoria.Add(new SelectListItem {
        Text = categoria.Nombre, 
        Value = categoria.CategoriaId.ToString(), 
        Selected = producto.CategoriaId == categoria.CategoriaId
    });
}
```

Using the debugger, I can confirm that the correct value is being set to "Selected = True".

My model:

```
public class ProductoModel
{
    public int ProductoId { get; set; }

    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Categoria { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Caracteristicas { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Precio - Categoria 1")]
    public decimal PrecioCatUno { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Precio - Categoria 2")]
    public decimal PrecioCatDos { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Precio - Categoria 3")]
    public decimal PrecioCatTres { get; set; }
}
```

In my editor template:

```
<div class="input-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Categoria)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaId, Model.Categoria)
</div>
```

Anybody know why the correct dropdown value isn't being selected despite the fact that I have set "selected" to true on the correct value?

Comment: how does your model look like

Comment: What does the produced HTML on the page look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
EfCategoriaRepository efCategoriaRepository = new EfCategoriaRepository();
model.Categoria= efCategoriaRepository.FindAllCategorias().Select(x=>new SelectListItem{
                Value=x.CategoriaId.ToString(), 
                Text = x.categoria.Nombre
           }).ToList();


    model.CategoriaId= producto.CategoriaId;
```